# how do I parameterise the urls in selenium

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using selenium to test number of web pages in one test suite. is there any way of parameterizing the urls? I tried doing it using javascript file, like, added url in js file, and used that variable in href tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code for same  with js file which include
var URL=new Array("www.asd.com","www.asd.com","www.asdd.com","www.asdsa.com","www.asdda.com");

```
     <tr>
            <td>store</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>looptimes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>while</td>
            <td>storedVars.looptimes <= 1</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>getEval</td>
            <td>alert("start")</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>storeEval</td>
            <td>URL[storedVars.looptimes]</td>
            <td>URL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>open</td>
            <td>${URL} </td>
        </tr>

<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars.looptimes++;}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>    
    <tr>
            <td>endWhile</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/01/selenium-resources-for-newbs-data-driven-testing-with-ide-xml/

Using this solution you can run each test case in a loop (each time using different url) then selenium will switch to next test case in test suite...

Test case would look like this:

```
loadTestData    | file:///listofURLs.xml

while | !testdata.EOF()

nextTestData |

open | ${variableURL}

verifyTextPresent | sometext

verifyTextPresent | sometext

endWhile |
```